# 550 Sender verify failed

Tags: exim

Скрипт отправляет письма с сайта site1.ru.
Письмо отправляется по нескольким адресам, через заголовки:

```
To: example.mail@yandex.ru
Copy: mail@test.ru
CC: copy@yandex.ru
```

Письма доставляются для example.mail@yandex.ru и copy@yandex.ru, а для mail@test.ru - письмо принимает статус frozen.

Файл заголовков:

```
1qHeDb-0003NB-0h-H
Debian-exim 101 103
<>
1688708483 0
-ident Debian-exim
-received_protocol local
-body_linecount 47
-max_received_linelength 253
-allow_unqualified_recipient
-allow_unqualified_sender
-frozen 1688708483
-localerror
XX
1
webmaster@example.com

151P Received: from Debian-exim by server.ru with local (Exim 4.84_2)
        id 1qHeDb-0003NB-0h
        for webmaster@example.com; Fri, 07 Jul 2023 09:41:23 +0400
035  X-Failed-Recipients: mail@test.ru
029  Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
058F From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@server.ru>
026T To: webmaster@example.com
059  Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
047I Message-Id: <E1qHeDb-0003NB-0h@server.ru>
038  Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2023 09:41:23 +0400
```

Файл данных:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  mail@test.ru
    SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<mail@test.ru>:
    host mail.example.ru [xx.xxx.xx.xxx]: 550 Sender verify failed

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <webmaster@example.com>
Received: from usertest by server.ru with local (Exim 4.84_2)
        (envelope-from <webmaster@example.com>)
        id 1qHeDa-0003N1-95; Fri, 07 Jul 2023 09:41:22 +0400
To: example.mail@yandex.ru
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?I=?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 601:tools.php
From: no-reply@site1.ru
CC: copy@yandex.ru
Reply-To: example.mail@mail.ru
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2023 08:41:22 +0300
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MID: 199.10 (07.07.2023 08:41:22)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-Id: <E1qHeDa-0003N1-95@server.ru>
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Ящики no-reply@site1.ru, mail@test.ru существуют.

- no-reply@site1.ru - на server.ru,
- mail@test.ru на server2.ru

(server.ru и server2.ru - VPS на хостинге ruweb.net).